# Canvas not resized properly to div (scroll bar issue??)

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, scroll

I don't know if anybody ever noticed this, but I'll give it a try.

Because the canvas behaves differently from other HTML elements, I use the resize event to resize it rather than CSS. This works well,

except when the browser is resized from maximized to normal, in which case the canvas is smaller than the div. The difference is about

the width of a scrollbar. In fact, when I make the canvas big enough to enforce a scrollbar, this doen't happen.

Has this anything to do with timing of the resize event? Does anybody know how to solve it?

## edit

This is true for IE9 (right side) and Safari (bottom and right side). But not for Chrome and FF.

fiddle over here -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxVWJ/)

## /edit

```
window.onload = function()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener('resize', doTheResize, false);
}

function doTheResize()
{
    canvas.width = div.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = div.clientHeight;
    drawThings();
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your misbehaving results in IE10...do you have a complete example I can look at.

Comment: It may be worth setting the scroll bar to always be visible using `html {overflow-y: scroll;}` in your css and see if it is in face the scrollbar showing/hiding that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jeremy This resizes the canvas correctly. It also resizes correctly if the call to the resize function is delayed.

Comment: @markE I've added an example. Just maximize and the normalize the IE or Safari browser and you'll see it has not resized properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the width and height and make the canvas that size.

**[Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/j7nCY/4/)**

[Full Screen](http://fiddle.jshell.net/j7nCY/4/show/light/)

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width:600px;
}
```

### JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().height;

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

window.onresize = function () {
    canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: but I use a div not the entire document

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe I changed my answer try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: I played around with your code and I discovered that the problem is in the container/div CSS, i.e. width vs right. For some reason right fails.